# Video files don't load, audio is missing

Tags: rendering, blend-files, audio

so I downloaded a template file for a youtube intro and it has 4 files in it but when i opened the blender file the other videos didn't open with blender, also the audio doesn't work.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is asking about issues with a template, and not Blender.

Comment: Just so you know, asking about issues with a template doesn't make much sense here. Especially since you didn't link to the template. If you have issues with these types of things, ask the creator or someone with experience with it to help you.

Comment: @TARDISMaker Why would the OP using a template necessarily mean the question is off-topic? It seems to me that the question is about audio/video files not working as expected (which IMO is a perfectly reasonable question). That said, we'll need some more info. Could you link to the files in question?

Comment: What format are those files in? How are you importing them to blender?

Comment: I smell absolute paths ....